# Water conductivity discovery

Tags: biographical-details

I read how Benjamin Franklin does the kite experiment in rain but keeping himself and the bottom end dry.I want to know how he know that water can conduct electricity.Please refer the link below and please see the Franklin's kite experiment section which is marked in green colour
http://lnr.li/0rvd6

Comment: Hi,  it seems you're doing rather a detailed bit of research.  Rather than asking a long sequence of questions here, perhaps you should start by finding some good biographies and history-of-science books to get a better understanding of the overall topic first.

Comment: Please anybody answer this question I want to know

Comment: At the time they had more experience with static electricity. Static electricity works best in dry conditions, it leaks away through moisture. No ammeter was needed for that discovery.

Comment: You should add your efforts in the question as well. Did you try Google Scholar. I will let you start from 1801 "Experiments on the chemical production and agency of electricity" and from there you go backwards to the time of Volta and earlier. Franklin book is also online from Internet Archives. https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/abs/10.1098/rstl.1801.0024